Understanding Accumulation point
Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence. Let $F$ be the set of all accumulation points of the sequence. My professor then wrote that $$F=\bigcap_{n\ge0}\{x_m| m\ge n\}$$
which intuitvely at first glance makes sense: step by step by increasing $n$ we eliminate all sequence points which do not occur infinitely many times - so we're left with the accumulation points.
But now my questions is, consider the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}$. The set $F$ should be $\{-1,1\}$ as $\pm1$ are its accumulation points. But with our intersection formula for $F$ this doesn't make sense to me as the two values $\pm1$ never actually are elements of the individual sequences. And  if we take an intersection of multiple sets which do not contain a certain element, the element cannot in my understanding be in the final intersection set.

Your instructor's definition of accumulation points seems a bit eccentric.

That's not the definition. It was part of an exercise to show that $F$ is closed.

@bochner.martinelli Please clarify what you mean. You don't say in your question that this was "part of an exercise to show that $F$ is closed." Please make your question self-contained.

Accumulation points need not be elements of the sequence.
